# Can we change the contrast of questions which have at least one of our favourite tags? (For Chem.SE)

Tags: feature-request, status-planned, design, tag-watching

I asked the question on [meta chemistry stackexchange](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3623/can-we-change-the-contrast-of-questions-which-have-at-least-one-of-our-favourite) about the difference of contrast which is less obvious for us in [Chem.SE](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/) than in [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/) for example.

We will be glad if someone can help us.

The support team told me it was the best place to ask my question. I hope this is the case. Thank you in advance.

Comment: i don't think it's duplicate. it's about one specific site (Chemistry) which actually uses different shade of yellow for highlighted questions. anyway, i'm working on a fix which should be in repo soon.

Comment: But in such case, doesn't it belong to their meta site? @Paweł

Comment: @ShadowWizard you're right. i'm not sure why it was asked again on meta.SE.. anyway, I will continue status updates on their meta site. feel free to remove those comments if you want.

Comment: @Paweł Ok, now I'm really confused. How is this completed? (nothing changed on Chemistry site, and the original meta question there is planned.)

Comment: @Paweł did it because someone told me it will be more visible.

Comment: @ShadowWizard please discard previous status update. my mind is playing tricks with me..

Comment: @Paweł lol, all good. Was just confused by all of this.